# Java SE and Scala Standard Library - cases when one of them is preferable

Tags: java, scala, frameworks, libraries

We all know that one can use Java libraries from Scala and vice versa. But even looking over the surface of Java SE and Scala standard library, we can notice that there are many parts in them that solve identical or at least similar problems. The trivial examples are collections, concurrency and IO. I am not an expert in either of two, but I suspect that in general Java SE is broader in size while Scala SL contains more conceptually advanced features (such as actors). The question is, if we have access to both libraries and have an opportunity to use both languages, are there some recommendations when we should choose Java SE features over Scala SL?

Comment: It's hard to tell wihtou a precise use case. Scala only project / mixed project / java project / which technology stack? which library... Your choice must be consistent with your environment.

Comment: I use mostly Scala collections and libraries as well designed and idiomatic with fall-back to java ones when such functionality is not presented in scala's or (rarely) when I find out that they are performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala Libraries fit into two general categories:

1. Original Scala Libraries. These are entirely (or almost entirely) written in Scala. Usually, people will write libraries from scratch for good reasons. Maybe Java lacks a similar library, or maybe whoever wrote the Scala one thinks the Java equivalent has serious limitations.

Collections is one such example.

1. Scala Wrappers over Java Libraries. In these cases, Scala uses an adapter pattern (or one of the other similar patterns) to provide a Scala-friendly API. These APIs are more fluent, integrate well with important Scala classes (such as collections and `Option`), and often make use of powerful Scala features such as traits to decrease boilerplate.

These libraries rarely offer more functionality than what Java provides, but reduces boilerplate enormously and makes code using them more idiomatic. Often, however, they present just a subset of the total functionality provided by Java. Depending on the library, it may or may not be possible or easy to extend it by accessing the underlying Java classes.

Scala Swing is great example of these.

In the particular case of `scala.io`, that is not so much a library as a crude wrapper just to handle simple common scripting tasks with an idiomatic Scala API. It's adequate for that -- and certainly much kinder on my eyes than `java.io` --, but not for any serious I/O. There's a *real* I/O library for Scala currently undergoing evaluation for adoption.

Another example I like a lot if `scala.sys.process`. It wraps over Java's `Process` and `ProcessBuilder`, providing almost all of the functionality, and adding some. Furthermore, you can use most of Java internals if needed (the sole exception is `Process` itself, which isn't really much useful).

My advice is to use Scala libraries were they exist and fit your needs, extend them if they are mostly adequate, but reach for Java libraries without hesitation otherwise. After all, having a high degree of interoperability with Java *is* a key feature of Scala.

Answer (score 4):

In general, when writing in Scala, I would advise always using the Scala libraries over the Java ones. My advice on specific areas would be:

- Collections - Scala's are much better, and I would always prefer them over the Java equivalents. Scala does however lack a mutable TreeMap, so if you need that sort of structure you'll have to go back to Java.
- Concurrency - Scala's concurrency features wrap Java's and are more advanced. I'd always pick them.
- IO - I think this is one area where Scala is narrower in what it supports. I would generally use a Scala `Source` when possible, but there may be more unusual situations where you'll have to drop back to Java IO (or possibly use a third party library).
- Swing - Last time I looked, Scala's swing wrapping wasn't complete, so if you're doing a lot of Swing related stuff, you might take the decision to use Java's swing components everywhere for consistency.

Comment: It's easy to extend Scala Swing by wrapping java components, though.