# What parts of Java (Standard library) do you need to know to write Scala code?

Tags: scala

What parts of Java (Standard library) do you need to know to write Scala code?

I'm teaching myself Scala and I'm really loving the language but I'm a little disturbed that you also have to know some of the Java standard library to write Scala code.

I'm not a Java programmer so I'm curious what 'main' parts of the Java standard library are not represented in the Scala standard library?

Comment: This question is probably too broad for SO. But, for instance, I always refer to the JavaDocs for regexes (aka Pattern). Also, java.util.concurrent is essential. That's why both your answers have the form, "Yes and no."

Comment: Why does it matter whether a class comes from a Java or Scala package? Why would you feel better if Scala had rewritten its own version of everything in the Java core?

Comment: @ChrisMartin: Well, for one, because Scala is in no way tied to Java. There are (dormant) .NET and native implementations of Scala as well as a rather vibrant one for ECMAScript. I believe, there's also plans for one on the Parrot VM and one on the Rubinius VM, and I know people are interested in one on the Swift/Cocoa/iOS platform. None of those have the Java ecosystem available. Note that specifying behavior and re-implementing behavior are not the same thing. E.g., the Java Language Specification specifies the behavior of Arrays independently of the JVM, but still uses their implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not required to know Java (Standard Libraries) for using Scala (does help in some cases). As for the libraries can be classified to two types:

**Original Scala Libraries** which are written in Scala and **Scala Wrappers over Java Libraries** which provide a Scala-friendly API.

There is an informative stackoverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941915/java-se-and-scala-standard-library-cases-when-one-of-them-is-preferable) (for more info).

Answer (score 1):

You definitely don't *need* to know any Java to use Scala - the standard library includes everything you'll need at a basic level, and plenty beyond that.

That said, the Java standard library is very large and complete. There are going to be parts that don't exist in Scala. That said, thanks to the fact that calling Java code from Scala is not difficult, it's not a matter of needing to 'know' the Java standard library. If you find you need something that isn't in the Scala standard library, and you find it in the Java standard library, you can use it.

If anything, it's just another option, thanks to the shared underlying architecture.

Comment: I think this answer is too optimistic. There are standard facilities like Regex and Process where you really have to be able to consult the underlying JavaDocs.

Comment: @som-snytt I don't think that's the same as needing to 'know the standard library', you just need to look at those parts as you need them. It's not a significant barrier. The question seems to be about a fear that the Java standard library increases the amount you need to learn to deal with Scala. My point is that there is no real barrier between Scala and Java that makes it an issue.

Comment: Java is large, but "very complete" is a lie.

Comment: Ok, you could rephrase to say that, but I think having to read JavaDoc with Java syntax is a barrier if it is unfamiliar.